# Python list data analysing

Tags: python, list, average

I need to make a little program in python where I have to analyse data in a list. 
List has these columns: country, year, mens immigration, mens emigration, womens immigration, womens emigration

What I have to do is ask the user which country they want to get the info for at first. Program needs to  get the average emigration over the years and also print out when has the emigration exceeded the average. Finally I have to print out a tabel which has the countries names and years when immigration exceeded emigration.

I am still a beginner and I have been having trouble writing this. I hope its not that difficult.

Comment: Share your trouble and what you done, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [
    # some made-up numbers for illustration
    ("France", 2006, 64026, 72527, 87442, 98435),
    ("France", 2007, 82051, 75285, 97193, 69527),
    ("France", 2008, 88827, 51960, 77807, 81725),
    ("Germany", 2006, 85653, 83989, 66603, 66559),
    ("Germany", 2007, 85431, 83590, 88482, 87827),
    ("Germany", 2008, 67184, 96350, 84947, 67874),
    ("Greece", 2006, 72062, 55844, 51758, 53004),
    ("Greece", 2007, 58566, 62006, 65323, 80320),
    ("Greece", 2008, 71298, 69158, 74774, 93267)
]

def average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / (len(lst) or 1)

def main():
    # prompt for country
    country = input("For which country? ")

    # filter data by specified country
    country_data = [row for row in data if row[0]==country]

    # get average yearly emigration
    avg_emigration = average([row[3] + row[5] for row in country_data])

    # print years in which emigration exceeds average
    print("Above-average emigration in:")
    for row in country_data:
        if row[3] + row[5] >= avg_emigration:
            print(row)

    # I'll leave the last bit for you to figure out;
    # very similar to the preceding clause

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
>>> main()
For which country? France
Above-average emigration in:
('France', 2006, 64026, 72527, 87442, 98435)
```